# jQuery active button children

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu ul").children('li').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    var wpl = window.location.pathname;
    if( href.indexOf(wpl) != -1 ){
      if( wpl.indexOf( "category" ) != -1){
        $("#products").attr('id','prodon');
      }
      if( wpl.indexOf( "news" ) != -1){
        $("#news").attr('id','newson');
      }
      if( wpl.indexOf( "wheretobuy" ) != -1){
        $("#WTB").attr('id','WTBon');
      }....
```

It goes on a little longer, different buttons.
I've only done it this way because each button is an image so they're all unique. This is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<li><a href="/news/index" id="news"></a></li>
<li>
  <a href="/site/wheretobuy" id="WTB"></a>
  <ul>
    <?php echo '<li>'.CHtml::link(CHtml::encode("Showrooms"), array('/showroom/index')).'</li>'; ?>
    <?php echo '<li>'.CHtml::link(CHtml::encode("Dealers"), array('/dealers/index')).'</li>'; ?>
    <?php echo '<li>'.CHtml::link(CHtml::encode("Hypermarket and Merchants"), array('/hyper/index')).'</li>'; ?>
  </ul>
</li>
```

So the parent nodes are all fine. Also, if a child's URL contains the parent's URL (i.e. category/cat), it shows the active button. I want to know how to apply a parent;s active img if one of its children is the URL, but not the same wording. I could do a bunch of more IFs but I think there's an easier way.

EDited.... again

```
  if( wpl.indexOf( "wheretobuy" ) != -1 || $('#menu ul').find('.WTBon').parent().closest('li').indexOf( "wheretobuy" ) != -1 ) { 

    $('.WTB').addClass('WTBon');

}
```

So what I'm trying to check is if the parent of the node has wheretobuy in the URL

Comment: Please give an example string of a situation where you'd set an image to a parent and one where you wouldn't.

Comment: @ TheWeirdNerd I would set an image to all parents. On my HTML if I go to 'showroom/index' I want the active image to be set for 'wheretobuy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

instead adding ids `add as class name`.

```
$('#menu ul').find('.idon').parent()
             .closest('li').addClass('.idon'); // <--id like //newson//
```

### updates for latest one:

```
if($('#menu li a[href*="wheretobuy"]').length){
   $('#menu a[href*="wheretobuy"]').parent('li').addClass('WTBon');
}
```

### Note:

Using same ids for multiple elems on a single page is discouraged. Its not a good practice.

`This applies in your case too` because `you have applied it by making the active one as id`, You can `use it as a class instead`.

Comment: Using the same IDs for multiple elements in the same document is actually illegal as per the spec.

Comment: Ohhhhh... hah, I was wondering why he was changing the id's I get it now. Yah, that's no good at all. Classes are the way to go; I use them as on off switches all the time even.

Comment: @Tomalak yup thats what i mentioned and suggested to change to classes instead.

Comment: Damn now I'm a criminal! I will try what Jai suggested and get back. I guess the trick is to use the .closest method.

Comment: Forgive me I'm a little novice in Jquery... So I classed up my code (YEAAAAHHHH) Now I'm trying to accomplish my question. Going by what Jai suggested this is what I got check Question

Comment: This is not doing what you need.

Comment: Yh you're right, I tried another if you can check on the question plz. Thanks

Comment: wait i will post another one too.

Comment: Jai thanks for all the help but it's not working... Can I ask what condition you are checking with the .length and how it works.  Thanks

Comment: .length is just for checking if such elemen exists or not, if yes then should be get affected.

Comment: I see, I was intending to highlight this  <li> <a href="/site/wheretobuy" id="WTB">Something</a> if I'm on this page <li>asdfasdfasdfasdf</li>